# .htaccess rewrite rule condition doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a rewrite rule but is not possible to me to find the correct expression. I've been searching in different kind of regular expression validators and they say that the expression works.

My `.htaccess` looks as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.+)=([a-zA-Z]+)&([a-z]+)=([a-zA-Z]+)&([a-z]+)=([a-zA-Z]+)&([a-z]+)=(.*)$ /$3+$5+$7 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

The example URI is: `http://www.example.com/index.php?r=site/action&param1=value1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule, you need to either use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` or `%{THE_REQUEST}` variables.

Although it's entirely unclear what you're trying to do, try something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?(.+)=([a-zA-Z]+)&([a-z]+)=([a-zA-Z]+)&([a-z]+)=([a-zA-Z]+)&([a-z]+)=(.*)
RewriteRule ^ /%3+%5+%7 [L]
```

Comment: what I'm trying to do is that the rewrite rule substitutes the uri by the parametres that I want. P.ex. substitutes /index.php?r=site/action&param1=value1 by /value1. Thanks for your answer!